# ulimit value when output is "hard" or "soft"

Tags: aix, ulimit

Can someone explain to me how can I determine actual values of for ulimit when the output of ulimit command is "hard" or "soft".
This is on AIX machine.
For example:

```
# ulimit -f
hard
```

And on another machine:

```
$ ulimit -m
soft
```

Since i don't have root access on this machines how can I know what are the exact values for this limits?

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: bash. I just tried ksh, and in this the limit is correctly displayed. Why is bash different?

Comment: bash doesn't behave like that on Ubuntu. What does `type ulimit` say?

Comment: # type ulimit
ulimit is a shell builtin

Comment: Which version of bash?  The standard AIX IBM version of bash works fine.  What do you get from `which bash`

Answer (score 2):

There's something odd about your `bash`.  Are you sure you don't have either an alias for `ulimit`, or a non-IBM AIX version of `bash`?

```
$ which bash
/usr/bin/bash
$ bash
$ oslevel -s
6100-08-01-1245
$ ulimit -f
unlimited
$ ulimit -m
32768
```